# Displaying a Variant Array Value in the Immediate Window

Tags: excel, vba, variant-array

I'm using a third party add-in, which seems to work ok.  However, I'm not able to display the value of a variant array element in the immediate window.  I have found ways around it, but I'd still like to know what the problem is and how to workaround it.

There is an object variable which contains data.

```
Dim odsDataSeries As DataSeries
Set odsDataSeries = odfData.GetSeries("ELY(high)")
```

In the Watch Window you can see the variant array called "Index" ...

[image]

In the immediate window I type...

```
?odsDataSeries.Index(1)
```

but it gives error message "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

If I use join then I get the data...

```
?join(odsDataSeries.Index)
3/01/2020 2/01/2020 31/12/2019 etc...
```

In my code I was also able to write...

```
Dim v As Variant
v = odsDataSeries.Index
Stop
```

Then when I query an element in v in the Immediate Window, it works...

```
?v(1)
2/01/2020
```

So my question is...Why didn't my Immediate Window query "?odsDataSeries.Index(1)" work?  For a while I thought Index wasn't public and I couldn't write a loop to process the array (and I still can't unless I put the array in another variable as shown above).  Note that writing this in my code gives the same error message (on compiling).

I'm adding my whole sub for reference.  Note that I used early binding.  The excel add-in is a .xll file and I can't see the code inside (because I haven't got COM skills yet).

```
Dim av As New AlphaVantageExcelDataCOMFunctions

Public Sub PublicLoadData()
On Error GoTo 0
Dim odfData As DataFrame
    Set odfData = av.AVGetEquityTimeSeries("ELY", "Daily", True, "compact")
Dim odsDataSeries As DataSeries
    Set odsDataSeries = odfData.GetSeries("ELY(high)")
Dim v As Variant
    v = odsDataSeries.Index
    Debug.Print GetVariableType(odsDataSeries.Index)
    Stop
End Sub 'PublicLoadData
```

My GetVariableType() function returns "Array of Variant".  Let me know if you want this code.

So the problem, again, is...In the immediate window I type...

```
?odsDataSeries.Index(1)
```

but it gives error message "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

If I use join then I get the data...

```
?join(odsDataSeries.Index)
3/01/2020 2/01/2020 31/12/2019 etc...
```

When I query an element in v in the Immediate Window, it works...

```
?v(1)
2/01/2020
```

[Here is a link to the DataSeries Documentation](https://alphavantage.github.io/Excel%20Addin%20Online%20Docs/VBA%20API%20Documentation/html/T_AlphaVantage_ExcelDataAddin_DataSeries.htm)

Comment: The `Index` property is not an array.

Comment: Just guessing, maybe `?odsDataSeries(1)`  works.

Comment: Try `? odsDataSeries.Index()(0)`

Comment: @Storax ?odsDataSeries(1) doesn't work.  That is the problem.  That is why I wrote the question.

Comment: @omegastripes ? odsDataSeries.Index()(0) works.  You're a genius!  Now tell me why it works.

Comment: Could you please show in your code the exact line you having issue with? Put the array in a variable prior to a loop.

Comment: I've now written the problem again below the new sub.

Comment: Why not just to use `? odsDataSeries.Index()(1)` irregardles of early or late binding? I guess it just doesn't designed to be used in enums e. g. `For Each i In odsDataSeries` and should be `For Each i In odsDataSeries.Index` (unlike Dictioanary which do the same for `For Each i In dict` and `For Each i In dict.Keys`), that is why you need extra brackets.

Comment: Yeah I guess I have to use the extra parenthesis.  I checked the assignment `v = odsDataSeries.Index`, and it also works with the extra parenthesis.  So I guess it's a get property.  I originally thought it was a public variable when I saw it in the Watch Window.  I'm still getting familiar with all these idiosyncrasies.

Comment: As far as writing a loop goes, I will now create the extra variable to hold the array and loop through that rather than odsDataSeries.  I generally don't like copying things about, but this time I will have to do it to save the array going back and forth constantly.  I understand it better now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say there is an object `someObject` with a method (or property) `getArray` having no input arguments and returning an array.

You may retrieve an array by doing `arr = someObject.getArray` which is the same as `arr = someObject.getArray()` with no arguments passed explicitly. To retrieve a single element from that array by one line code you should do `someObject.getArray()(0)`, where the first parentheses refer to the method call, and the second indicate the index of the element in the array.

Note, although the expression `someObject.getArray()(i)` is good for single element request, e. g. in Immediate window, but if used in loops, it might result in a lot of overhead to retrieve the array each iteration. So you should put the array into variable prior to the loop.

Here is the example showing some tricky behavior of commonly used `Dictionary` object. You can retrieve an element from array of keys returned by method simply by `dict.Keys(i)` with early bind:

```vb
Sub testEarlyBoundDict()

    ' Need to include a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"

    Dim earlyBoundDict As Dictionary
    Set earlyBoundDict = New Dictionary
    Set earlyBoundDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    earlyBoundDict("myKey") = "myValue"
    Debug.Print earlyBoundDict.Keys(0)

End Sub
```

But if you use late bind then you have to write additional parentheses:

```
Sub testLateBoundDict()

    ' Need no references

    Dim lateBoundDict As Object
    Set lateBoundDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    lateBoundDict("myKey") = "myValue"
    Debug.Print lateBoundDict.Keys()(0)
    Debug.Print lateBoundDict.Keys(0) ' fails

End Sub
```

To create fail-proof code I would suggest always use `someObject.getArray()(i)`.

Comment: If I got the OP's post right then his variables are early bound, right? Of course, upvoted.

Comment: I've added more information to my question.  You can see I used early binding.  I'm still somewhat confused.